# Help speed up website performance, especially in IE8

Tags: performance, optimization, web

Where would you start if you were trying to make this webpage load faster?

Site: [Game-On Glove](http://www.gameonglove.com/)

It is JavaScript heavy because the goal was a one-page layout with light-boxed checkout. The hosting platform creates some limitations in the server side code department.

If there's a Flash or JavaScript banner that anyone knows of that looks as nice, is XML-driven, and actually takes advantage of parallel downloads, please let me know. I chose to pre-load the bunch of 250px images that appear in our Flash gallery to take advantage of parallel downloads, which our Flash banner of choice doesn't take advantage of.

Apart from that though, in the Firefox Firebug NET tab I see:

1. Initial gameonglove.com request takes 6.75s. This seems high. I wonder if I could start reducing it by packaging up most of the JavaScript into external files.
2. To reduce our massive number of images I could replace the white background with grey borders with some kind of rounded border instead of dedicating an image for each background.
3. Facebook, addthis.com, and google-analytics.com downloads take about 7s, and put the rest of the page load on hold. Problem being, they wait for the `onLoad` event to fire I believe. I'm not sure what else to use as the event trigger, but I probably shouldn't have to resort to something else.
4. I'm not entirely sure which hostnames to keep, and which ones to host on our server to optimize our DNS to parallel download ratio.

> Avoiding DNS lookups cuts response times, but reducing parallel downloads may increase response times. My guideline is to split these components across at least two but no more than four hostnames. http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd start by profiling with something like dynaTrace Ajax Edition.

Comment: Did you try Google Chrome with SpeedTracer? It's pretty neat for these kind of problems.

Comment: I haven't checked into those two tools. I've used the Google Timeline and Firefox's Yslow and Page Speed add-ons, and the Firebug NET tab to observe how and when files are downloaded. I've also used the Chrome and Firefox Profilers but I didn't find them particularly helpful.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com), which purely measures time to download objects (no JavaScript processing time or anything like that).

I tested your site and it looks like it needs >1.7MiB of information, which could be partially where your slowdown is occurring.

Comment: That is a pretty awesome tool. But yeah, I'm sure that's partially where the slowdown happens. I'm just not sure what pieces are hurting the speed the most (or even if there's a way to determine that) so I can start there.

Answer (score 2):

The number of files, that site is loading, really hurts performance.  [Studies](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/28/performance-research-part-1/) show that the overhead per file as a much vaster effect than filesize (for typical script, image, CSS files).

So some things to do:

1. Consolidate Javascript into as few files as reasonable.
2. [Use the `Async` and `Defer` attributes to stop JS from slowing page loads](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2010/10/19/non-blocking-async-defer/).
3. Consolidate CSS into as few files as reasonable.
4. Merge images into [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).
5. Make sure your server is caching files!
6. Turn on Gzip encoding at the server.
7. Avoid Redirects (301, 302) as much as possible (but preserve old URL's or lose customers).  Check the web-server logs to identify and fix problems.
8. Get a faster site/domain host. :)

See also:

- [Website optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2840214/331508)
- [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
- [Webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)